# How to test mutableStateFlow when previewing a composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a composable where I want to simulate a changing input with a mutablestateflow. Simply put, I have a composable where you pass in a string field called item description which the composable displays. If the user types in a new description, the mutablestateflow should update to the newly entered description.
I'm trying to test out my compoent while developing it, without having to write a full blown viewmodel for it.

This is my composable:

```
@Composable
fun Foo(itemDescription: String, setItemDescription: (newDescription: String) -> Unit) {
 OutlinedTextField(value = itemDescription, onChange = { it -> setItemDescription(it) })
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to preview it:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewFoo() {
 val itemDescriptionMutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow("SomeInitValue")
 val itemDescriptionStateFlow = itemDescriptionStateFlow.asStateFlow()
 val itemDescription by itemDescriptionStateFlow.collectAsState()
 
 val itemDescription by itemDescription
 Foo(itemDescription = itemDescription, setItemDescription = {
  itemDescriptionMutableStateFlow.value = it
 })
}
```

But if I do this, whatever value I type into the the outlined text field, it keeps showing "SomeInitValue" which is the init value for the mutable state flow. This setup works if I use a viewmodel to store the mutablestateflow instead of directly using a mutablestateflow.

How do I simulate a mutablestateflow while testing my component? or what am I doing wrong here? Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that the Preview function is getting recomposed with every character typed.  This is causing `itemDescriptionMutableStateFlow` to be reinitialized every time and resetting the value of the text field in the preview.  You'll need to remember the `MutableStateFlow` to avoid this.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewFoo() {
    val itemDescriptionMutableStateFlow = remember {
        MutableStateFlow("SomeInitValue")
    }
    val text by itemDescriptionMutableStateFlow.collectAsState()

    Foo(itemDescription = text, setItemDescription = {
        itemDescriptionMutableStateFlow.value = it
    })
}
```

You could also use a `MutableState` for preview / testing purposes in this particular case.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewFoo() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("SomeInitValue") }

    Foo(itemDescription = text, setItemDescription = {
        text = it
    })
}
```

Comment: You're the man - you solved it :), Thanks!